# How to use reducer in hadoop mapeduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I am new to using reducer

Consider this as my inputfile

```
hi,how,1,a,b,are,you,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx
hi,how,1,a,b,are,you,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx
hi,how,1,a,b,i,am,yyyy,yyyy,yyyy
hi,how,1,a,b,i,am,yyyy,yyyy,yyyy
hi,how,2,a,b,are,you,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx
hi,how,2,a,b,are,you,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx
hi,how,2,a,b,i,am,yyyy,yyyy,yyyy
hi,how,3,a,b,are,you,yyyy,yyyy,yyyy
hi,how,3,a,b,i,am,yyyy,yyyy,yyyy
hi,how,4,a,b,are,you,yyyy,yyyy,yyyy
hi,how,4,a,b,are,you,yyyy,yyyy,yyyy
hi,how,4,a,b,i,am,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx
```

this is my map function

```
@Override
        public  void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
          String Str_line = value.toString();
          String[] input = Str_line.split(",");
          Text Outkey = new Text();
          Outkey.set(input[2]);
          context.write(Outkey),null);
         }
```

This is my reduce function

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                context.write(key, null);
            }
```

> i need output like this 
>        hi,how,1,are,you
>        hi,how,1,i,am
>        hi,how,2,are,you
>        hi,how,2,i,am
>        hi,how,3,are
>        hi,how,3,i,am
>        hi,how,4,are,you
>        hi,how,4,i,am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapper Code:-

```
  @Override
            public  void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
            {
              String Str_line = value.toString();
              String[] input = Str_line.split(",");

              Text Outkey = new Text();

              Outkey.set(input[0]+","+input[1]+","+input[2]+","+input[5]+","+input[6]);

              context.write(Outkey,NullWritable.get);
             }
```

Reducer Code:-

```
 public void reduce(Text Key,Iterable<NullWritable> Values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       context.write(NullWritable.get(),key);

        }
```

Comment: i am getting The method set(String) in the type Text is not applicable for the arguments (String[])...@madhu

Comment: pls see the input file i have edited it...can you pls give the code for this input file@madhu

Comment: if the column 4,5 is placed in 6,7 how can i give the input@madhu

Comment: if that is going to be case we can cut and place each words separately

Comment: I am getting this error-The constructor String(String[]) is undefined @madhu

Comment: Have changed the answer as per your latest input... check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94402/discussion-between-barath-and-madhu).